# drawing query trees using avg?

Tags: sql, database

I was wondering how would avg and group by represented in query trees?

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT  Stats.StuId, Stats.CrsAve
FROM        (SELECT T.StuId, AVG(T.Grd) AS CrsAvg
        FROM        Transcript T
        WHERE   T.Semester IN (‘F2004’, ‘S2006’)
        GROUP BY    T.StuId) AS Stats
WHERE       Stats.CrsAvg >  3.5
```

So, modules GROUP BY and AVG worry me - how are they drawn?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "Avg", but to optimize the query you can avoid using two select adding a clause "Having":

```
 SELECT T.StuId, AVG(T.Grd) AS CrsAvg
        FROM        Transcript T
        WHERE   T.Semester IN (‘F2004’, ‘S2006’)
        GROUP BY    T.StuId
having AVG(T.Grd) > 3.5
```

Also, you can consider adding appropriate indexes to the table.